# How do I create a custom button on an iOS keyboard within my app?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, ios6

I want to add a button to the left of the space bar (similar to the emoji globe) that when pressed produces a character within my app.

Answer (score 4):

Don't think you can do that.  However, you can add a small view above the keyboard by setting the `inputAccessoryView` (usually to a UIToolbar).

[Link to Blog Example](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2012/03/12/customizing-the-ios-keyboard/) (I didn't read, but looks like it should cover things)

Answer (score 3):

iOS has been designed such that that the keyboard is not customizable by the developers.

However, you can fake it by using a UIToolBar just above the keyboard (in fact many apple apps do exactly this - its well within human interface guidelines).

Here's a simple example: (the next/prev/done buttons):

[image]

***Open Source Substitute for the iOS Default Keyboard***

Alternatively, here is an OpenSource control that allow the creation of a keyboard that looks like the built-in one, but that allows custom keys.

https://github.com/kulpreetchilana/Custom-iOS-Keyboards